# SQL COUNT with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

I have a seemly simple question with SQL that I am having trouble figuring out.  Suppose I have the following tables:

```
company: 
    company_id
    company_title

users: 
    user_id
    username

company_owners: 
    company_id
    user_id
```

Now, there can be multiple users as company owners.  Here is some example data:

```
company:
1, "A Company"
2, "B Company"
3, "C Company"

users:
1, "A User"
2, "B User"
3, "C User"

company_owners:
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,3
```

I am trying to create a query (MySQL) that gets the company_title, as well as the number of owners for that company, based on a specific company owner.  So, for example:

Example query (in english) run:  Get number of owners for each company that "C User" is an owner for:

```
company_id=1, company_title="A Company", num_owners=3
company_id=2, company_title="B Company", num_owners=1
company_id=3, company_title="C Company", num_owners=0
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id), company.* FROM `company` 
LEFT JOIN `company_owners` ON company_owners.company_id = company.company_id 
WHERE company_owners.user_id=1 GROUP BY company_id
```

But that always gives me an ownership number of "1", I'm assuming because its only COUNTing the rows where user_id=1.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I can supply more detail if need be.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your WHERE clause should be "where there exists an owner for this company with user_id = 1".

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id), company.*
FROM `company` 
LEFT JOIN `company_owners`
ON company_owners.company_id = company.company_id 
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM company_owners AS co2
    WHERE company_owners.company_id = co2.company_id
    AND co2.user_id = 3
)
GROUP BY company_id
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f110/3)

Comment: That works great.  How would I change it so I can also get all the companies that have 0 owners?  This returns only the rows with more than 0 owners.

Comment: @Chris: It doesn't return companies with no owners because a company with no owners cannot be owned by "C".

Comment: That is an incredibly good point and I was thinking of something totally different!  Haha, sorry.  Thank you so much for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
select company.company_id, company_title, count(*)
from company join company_owners on company.company_id = company_owners.company_id
where exists (select 1 from company_owners co where co.user_id = 1 and co.company_id = company.company_id)
group by company.company_id, company_title
```